# Adjoint of skew-symmetric matrix

Tags: matrices, skew-symmetric-matrices

If $A$ is a skew-symmetric $n\times n$ matrix, verify that $\operatorname{adj} A$ is symmetric or skew-symmetric according to whether $n$ is odd or even.

Things I can think of is $A^T=-A$ for skew-symmetric matrix, and the other is $\operatorname{adj} A=(\operatorname{cofactor}A)^T$.

Answer (score 4):

Here are some hints.  Show that $$\operatorname{adj}(A^T)=(\operatorname{adj} A)^T$$ for every square matrix $A$.  Then, show that
$$\operatorname{adj}(-A)=(-1)^{n-1}\operatorname{adj} A$$
for every square matrix $A$ of order $n$.

Comment: How do we formulate adj(-A)=(-1)^n-1adjA, because i saw another one is like A^T=-A then det A=(-1)^ndetA

Comment: What is the definition of $\operatorname{adj} A$?  If you take a look at the definition carefully, your knowledge that $\det(-A)=(-1)^n\det A$ will become handy.